# How will a concat() in sql will add two or more arguements including special characters?

Tags: sql, concatenation

```
select CONCAT(address,city) as Address from student order by Address desc;
```

This is a query to display the address and the city with an alias name as Address from a student table

```
--- Program output ---

ADDRESS
----------------------------------------------------------------------
LMCCoimbatore
FFFVilupuram
BBBAgra
ABCSalem
AAAPondichery


--- Expected output (text)---
ADDRESS
------------------------------------------------------------------------
LMC, Coimbatore
FFF, Vilupuram
BBB, Agra
ABC, Salem
AAA, Pondichery
```

how can i add the coma and space between the city and address? when i use the third string as ', ' it is giving an invalid number of arguments error.

Comment: Which database engine are you using ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**CONCAT versions:**

I would recommend CONCAT since it will protect you from returning NULL when one of arguments is null - at least in MSSQL.

MSSQL & MySQL & PostgresSQL & Teradata:

```
select CONCAT(address,', ',city) as Address from student order by Address desc;
```

MySQL version 2:

```
select CONCAT_WS(', ', address,city) as Address from student order by Address desc;
```

Oracle & IBM DB2 & IBM Informix:

```
select CONCAT(address,CONCAT(', ',city)) as Address from student order by Address desc;
```

IBM DB2:

```
select address CONCAT ', ' CONCAT city as Address from student order by Address desc;
```

**Non-CONCAT versions:**

|| is ANSI standard, however not all systems use it.

MSSQL & Sybase IQ:

```
select address + ', ' + city as Address from student order by Address desc;
```

MySQL (so called proximity operator, default behavior):

```
select address ', ' city as Address from student order by Address desc;
```

PostgresSQL & Oracle & MySQL (with `SET sql_mode='PIPES_AS_CONCAT';`) & IBM Informix & Sybase IQ:

```
select address || ', ' || city as Address from student order by Address desc;
```

Comment: It will work with MS sql server but maybe not with another database engine

Comment: Only Oracle seems to be special in this case. Otherwise Postgres, MySQL work fin with it. Of course unless there is another RDBMS in use here.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answers, I'd like to mention that the standard (ISO 9075) concatenation operator in SQL is `||` but it isn't supported by all DB engines.

```
select address || ', ' || city
```

Oracle uses this one

Comment: @C-Champagne thanks for this - I have included it in my answer.

Comment: As far as I know, only 2 products do not support standard character strings concatenation : MS Access and MS SQL Server.

Comment: @FabianPijcke: and MySQL needs to be configured to comply with the SQL standard.

Comment: @RafalZiolkowski thanks. +1 for your exhaustive answer

Comment: :) Thanks! It turned out that this simple functionality has more variations than I thought and this was worth sharing.